# Versão mínima do android studio instala mas não abre

Tags: android, android-studio

Tenho um projeto que compila na versão `compileSdkVersion 28`, e coloquei a mínima para `minSdkVersion 18`, utilizo o celular para testar o app e funciona perfeito o meu é android 8.0 e estou tentando testar em um celular com android 4.3.

Ele instala mas ao abrir diz: app parou, o que seria isso?

Comment: qual o código de erro?

Comment: Olha o logCat não da nenhum erro, apenas informa que app parou. essa msg aparece tanto instalando o apk e quanto com o celular conectado na USB.

Comment: Criei um projeto novo pra teste com android 4.3 e funcionou, não sei o que isso.

Comment: oi pessoal, consegui resolver esse problema.

após o debug verifiquei que era alguma coisa relacionado ao `ImageView` dai exclui e inseri novamente.